# issue while generating panorama

Tags: python, opencv, panoramas

I have these 2 images with some overlap [image] [image]
When I try to generate a panorama out of them, I get some weird results. Here is the output image. How can I correct this? [image]

Here is the link to the code I am using: http://pastebin.com/9xirjc2A

Comment: 1. try to get more overlap of both images. 2. test whether the computed homographies make sense: looks like most of your images is warped to a single pixel.

Comment: how to check the homography?? 

I did take a look at matches between both the images and the matches lie mostly across checkboard. So basically I need matches well distributed across both images, right?

Comment: not necessarily. To check the homography there are different approaches, I don't remember them all. You could warp/transform some subimages (just the rects, not the pixels) and compare the area of the original and the warped regions. If they differ too much, there might be something wrong.